# ¿Cómo realizar la obtención del consumo de RAM con C#

Tags: c#

Mi pregunta es sencilla, necesito obtener los valores de memoria `RAM` *(memoria total, en uso y libre)* de un Equipo con `C#.`

Hasta ahora puedo obtener la memoria total mediante el uso de `PerformanceCounter`
pero desconozco si de la misma forma se puede obtener ya sea la memoria libre o la ocupada. De ser así, cuales serían el `CategoryName`, `CounterName` y el `InstanceName` para obtenerlos.

He buscado por todos lados y no encuentro nada que me pueda servir y todos me mandan con `WMI`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El siguiente programa muestra por consola el consumo de la memoria cada 1 segundo.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleUsoRam
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                double intervalo = 1000;
                Cronometro cron = new Cronometro(intervalo);
                cron.Iniciar();

                System.Console.ReadKey();
                TimeSpan final = cron.Detener();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + exc.ToString());
                System.Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Cronometro : Timer
    {
        private DateTime _inicio;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="intervalo">En milisegundos</param>
        public Cronometro(double intervalo)
        {
            base.Interval = intervalo;
            this.Elapsed += Tic;
        }

        public void Iniciar()
        {
            this._inicio = DateTime.Now;
            this.Start();
        }

        public TimeSpan Detener()
        {
            this.Stop();
            TimeSpan transcurrio = DateTime.Now - this._inicio;
            return transcurrio;
        }

        private void Tic(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {

            CalcularConsumoRAM();
        }

        /*
         * Basado en el codigo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028263/2141126
         */
        private static void CalcularConsumoRAM()
        {
            System.Console.Clear();
            Int64 phav = PerformanceInfo.GetPhysicalAvailableMemoryInMiB();
            Int64 tot = PerformanceInfo.GetTotalMemoryInMiB();

            decimal percentFree = ((decimal)phav / (decimal)tot) * 100;
            decimal percentOccupied = 100 - percentFree;

             Console.WriteLine("Memoria Fisica disponible (MiB)\t" + phav.ToString());
             Console.WriteLine("Memoria Total (MiB)\t\t" + tot.ToString());
             Console.WriteLine("Libre (%)\t\t\t" + percentFree.ToString("{0.0#}"));
             Console.WriteLine("Ocupada (%)\t\t\t" + percentOccupied.ToString("{0.0#}"));
        }
    }

    public static class PerformanceInfo
    {
        [DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool GetPerformanceInfo(
            [Out] out PerformanceInformation PerformanceInformation,
            [In] int Size);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PerformanceInformation
        {
            public int Size;
            public IntPtr CommitTotal;
            public IntPtr CommitLimit;
            public IntPtr CommitPeak;
            public IntPtr PhysicalTotal;
            public IntPtr PhysicalAvailable;
            public IntPtr SystemCache;
            public IntPtr KernelTotal;
            public IntPtr KernelPaged;
            public IntPtr KernelNonPaged;
            public IntPtr PageSize;
            public int HandlesCount;
            public int ProcessCount;
            public int ThreadCount;
        }

        public static Int64 GetPhysicalAvailableMemoryInMiB()
        {
            PerformanceInformation pi = new PerformanceInformation();
            if (GetPerformanceInfo(out pi, Marshal.SizeOf(pi)))
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64((pi.PhysicalAvailable.ToInt64() * pi.PageSize.ToInt64() / 1048576));
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }

        }

        public static Int64 GetTotalMemoryInMiB()
        {
            PerformanceInformation pi = new PerformanceInformation();
            if (GetPerformanceInfo(out pi, Marshal.SizeOf(pi)))
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64((pi.PhysicalTotal.ToInt64() * pi.PageSize.ToInt64() / 1048576));
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Basado en el código de StkOvf en ingles:https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028263/2141126

Comment: En efecto, después de buscar di con esa página que me fue de gran utilidad. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

He encontrado este enlace en StackOverflow en inglés y creo que responde a tu pregunta, el total de memoria, el total libre y el total usado. Puedes copiar el código que se entiende bien.

[Enlace a la respuesta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027341/c-sharp-get-used-memory-in)

Por otra parte, si lo que quieres es la memoria que utiliza el proceso actual tienes eso:

```
Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

proc.PrivateMemorySize64;
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos!!

Comment: En efecto, esa información me fue de bastante utilidad. Requiero hacer el monitoreo de la información de toda la memoria (no de un solo proceso), por ello monitorear un solo proceso no me es de utilidad.

Te agradezco mucho la liga, me sirvió bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el total de la ram, se ocupa agregar una referencia de VB:
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter MemoriaRam;
        Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo InformacionEquipo;
        double RAM_Disponible_GB = 0, RAM_Total_GB = 0, RAM_EnUsoGB = 0;

        MemoriaRam = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter();
        MemoriaRam.CategoryName = "Memory";
        MemoriaRam.CounterName = "Available Bytes";

        InformacionEquipo = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo();

        RAM_Total_GB = convertMBaGB((long)InformacionEquipo.TotalPhysicalMemory);
        RAM_Disponible_GB = convertiraGigas((long)MemoriaRam.NextValue());
        RAM_EnUsoGB = RAM_Total_GB - RAM_Disponible_GB;

        Console.WriteLine("Total: " + RAM_Total_GB);
        Console.WriteLine("Disponible: " + RAM_Disponible_GB);
        Console.WriteLine("En Uso: " + RAM_EnUsoGB);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static double convertiraGigas(long bytes)
    {
        return (bytes / (double)1024 / (double)1024 / 1024);
    }

    private static double convertMBaGB(long MB)
    {
        return (MB / (double)1024 / (double)1024 / (double)1024);
    }
```